# Inaccurate calculations (rounding?) - PHP

Tags: php, formula, rounding-error, arithmetic-expressions

Edit: Problem solved

I'm trying to port over a popular rating algorithm which analyses some statistics from  Counter-Strike matches into a PHP script. The outline of the system can be found in the link below (the bottom part of the news post):
http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=242&eventid=0

Anyway, so I've get everything set up in PHP, and I'm reasonably sure that everything is correct. For the purposes of calcuation, assume that:

```
$rating1K = 5;
$rating2K = 8;
$rating3K = 3;
$rating4K = 0;
$rating5K = 0;
$kills = 30
$deaths = 19
$round = 30
```

This is my code:

```
$kpr = $kills / $round; // kills per round
$killRating = ($kills / $round / $kpr); 

$spr = ($round - $deaths) / $round; // survivals per round
$survivalRating = ($round - $deaths) / $round / $spr;    

$averageRMK = ((1*$rating1K + 4*$rating2K + 9*$rating3K + 16*$rating4K + 25*$rating5K)/$round);
$roundsWithMultipleKillsRating = ((1*$rating1K + 4*$rating2K + 9*$rating3K + 16*$rating4K + 25*$rating5K)/$round/$averageRMK);

$rating = ($killRating + 0.7 * $survivalRating + $roundsWithMultipleKillsRating) / 2.7;
echo $rating;
```

The problem is that $killRating, $survivalRating and $roundsWithMultipleKillsRating always seem to return 1 in the PHP script, whereas if I calculate them manually myself they are different. For example, if I calculate $killRating myself, I get 1.5789-etc, but PHP returns "1".

What can I do this fix this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could also check your php.ini and see what precision your integers are using... upping this value would probably help. http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating wrong...

```
$kpr = $kills / $round; // kills per round
$killRating = ($kills / $round / $kpr);
```

equals

```
$kpr = 30 / 30; // 1
$killRating = (30 / 30 / 1); //1
```

And

```
$spr = ($round - $deaths) / $round; // survivals per round
$survivalRating = ($round - $deaths) / $round / $spr;
```

equals

```
$spr = (30 - 19) / 30; // 0.36666
$survivalRating = (30 - 19) / 30 / 0.3666; // 1
```

Your own calculation is wrong. PHP does everything fine here.

Please note that kpr being $kill/$round, when you devide $kill/$round/$kpr it will always be 1. Any number divided by itself equals 1. I can't beleive everyone is talking about floats and integers without even understanding mathematics...

Comment: I see now. You are right. I've just realized I had been using 19 for rounds instead of 30. What a terrible oversight. I never looked into the actual formula when porting it across and only assumed it was right, since it has been used in the Counter-Strike community for some years now. Perhaps I've gone wrong interpreting it when I wrote it in my code... or is rating formula just terribly incorrect?

Comment: After a few minutes of logical thinking, I have really realized how stupid this question has been. I've fixed the problem by fixing the formula itself. Thanks for your help, and in future I'll definitely be  more careful before resorting to posting a SO question. -_-

Comment: It's got nothing to do with understanding mathematics but everything to do with assumptions. People make poor assumptions every day, like assuming that those who have taken their time to give answers are unable to understand decimal division.

Answer (score 1):

```
$kills = 30;
$deaths = 19;
$round = 30;

$kpr = $kills / $round; // kills per round
$killRating = ($kills / $round / $kpr);
```

For KPR: kills / round = 30 / 30 = 1

For KillRating: kills / round / kpr = 30 / 30 / 1 = 1 (this is just kpr/kpr, why?)

PHP is giving you 1 as the answer to that part because the answer is 1.

Comment: Lol I hadn't even checked the Math in my answer :)

Comment: Thanks Dai, I had completely overlooked this at first. Turns out I had misinterpreted the formula layout and had copied it incorrectly. My own fault for not double checking things myself before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are dealing with `floats` instead of `integers`. Try casting them.